# Maven release failing : A zip file cannot include itself

Tags: maven

I am facing an issue while releasing a Maven project to nexus repository. I am doing this by Jenkins job. I am getting the error: 
`Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar (attach-sources) on project xyz: Error creating source archive: A zip file cannot include itself -> [Help 1]`

I am using `maven assembly plugin` and `external.atlassian.jgitflow:jgitflow-maven-plugin`.

I have followed below article on StackOveflow : [A zip file cannot include itself - Maven-assembly plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22396986/a-zip-file-cannot-include-itself-maven-assembly-plugin)

But this did not solve the problem. Below is how I am using the plugin

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.x</groupId>
<artifactId>y</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>2.0.0</version>
<name>myArtifact</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>myRepoId</id>
        <url>http://my/repo/location/releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>mySnapshotRepoId</id>
        <url>http://my/repo/location/snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>myRepoId</id>
        <url>http://my/repo/location/releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>mySnapshotRepoId</id>
        <url>http://my/snapshot/repo/location/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>local</build.profile.id>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>pre_prod</id>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>pre_prod</build.profile.id>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>prod</build.profile.id>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>external.atlassian.jgitflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>jgitflow-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-m5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <enableSshAgent>true</enableSshAgent>
                <allowUntracked>true</allowUntracked>
                <allowSnapshots>true</allowSnapshots>
                <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                <pushFeatures>true</pushFeatures>
                <pushReleases>true</pushReleases>
                <pushHotfixes>true</pushHotfixes>
                <noDeploy>false</noDeploy>
                <scmCommentPrefix>TC-61</scmCommentPrefix>
                <flowInitContext>
                    <developBranchName>development</developBranchName>
                    <versionTagPrefix>My-APP-</versionTagPrefix>
                </flowInitContext>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <tag>Release-${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</tag>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.mains.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <!-- here the phase you need -->
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources/config/${build.profile.id}</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources/velocities/html</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- START: Maven Jacoco Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.9</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which 
                    is passed as VM argument when Maven the Surefire plugin is executed. -->
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-instrument</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>instrument</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-restore-instrumented-classes</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <!-- Ensures that the code coverage report for unit tests is created 
                    after unit tests have been run. -->
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-report</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
</project>
```

Can someone point me where I am making the mistake.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the whole pom file and how you called Maven?

Comment: @khmarbaise I have edited the post to include the entire pom file.